# Iterable dataset exhausts after a single epoch

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I wanted to train an RNN on the task of sentiment analysis, for this task I was using the IMDB dataset provided by torchtext which contains 50000 movie reviews and it is a python iterator. I used a `split=('train', 'test')`.

I first built a vocab using `torchtext.vocab.Vocab` and tokenized each of the sentence and then performed numericalisation.

To pad the sequence to the same length I used `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence` and also used a `collate_fn` together with `batch_sampler`. Then I loaded the data using torch.utils.data.`DataLoader`.

The implementation of the RNN Network is fine but the dataloader is exhausted after a single epoch as you can see in the image attached below.

Am I following the right approach to load this iterable-dataset? and why is the dataloader exhausted after a single epoch and how do I overcome this issue.

Pleases refer to the shared colab notebook if you want to see my implementation.

PS. I was following the official [changelog](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb) of torchtext from github

You can find my implementation [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ep0s2D2d7fNhhUrYgPTtd5A74FPKsytg?usp=sharing)

[image: Dataloader exhausted after a single epoch]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `torchtext.data.functional.to_map_style_dataset(iter_data)` ([official doc](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/data_functional.html#to-map-style-dataset)) to convert your iterable-style dataset to map-style dataset.

Like this:

```
from torchtext.data.functional import to_map_style_dataset
train_iter = IMDB(split='train')
train_dataset = to_map_style_dataset(train_iter)  #Map-style dataset
```

and then make a dataloader.

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

### Why is this happening?

*I am using above example's naming convention to explain.*

The `train_iter` getting passed to `Dataloader` is an Iterable-style dataset which means it does not have `__getitem__` implemented. It only has `__iter__` and `__next__` dunders - which makes it a Iterable.

Therefore if I pass an iterable to the `Dataloader`, the dataloader stops after the `StopIteration` exception occurs - which will be thrown by `__next__` dunder of the iterable-style dataset(`train_iter` in this case) when the dataset(the iterable) got exhausted.

So we have used the `to_map_style_dataset` function to convert Iterable-style to map-style dataset. It does so by implementing a `__getitem__` dunder and thus `Dataloader` by default use indices to get items from the dataset.

#### Another possible way of doing the same thing can also be

If I'll go with iterable-style dataset - I need to create the `Dataloader` object at every epoch. So after each epoch the new dataloader object will run from start in the for loop.

For better understanding, the differences and use-cases for Iterable-style and Map-style datasets in Pytorch, refer this https://yizhepku.github.io/2020/12/26/dataloader.html

Comment: Let me know if I answered you question. Also please suggest edit if you believe my understanding is not right.

Comment: Your explanation implies that it's impossible to do multiple epochs on an IterableDataset without fundamentally changing the rest of the code.  That seems wrong - at least I hope that's wrong.

Comment: @Leopd I have the same concern right now! In fact I made an `IterableDataset` and it never moves from Epoch 0 -> 1. It just keeps incrementing the batch count forever. I don't know what the solution is and it seems very obvious it's a problem!